# Absorbing Radiation

Tags: science-fiction, warfare, radiation, nuclear-war

Everything was fine and dandy on planet Earth until a stargate like portal appeared and connected Earth to a different version of Earth aka Earth2. On this other Earth, humanity evolved differently, their control of chemistry and biology (and subsequent control over the environment) far outpaced what humans on our Earth could have ever dreamed off. As a result, their reliance on technology isn't about the same as us. But that's aside the point. Humans being humans tried peace and decided eventually that peace was never an option.

War eventually broke out nuclear weapons ended up flying. From Earth you have your run of the mill nuclear warheads. Traditional nukes where the radiation doesn't last very long. But then a new class of weapons, dirty bombs. The nasty types that were designed to detonate on the ground, kick up as much contaminated radiation and infect and screw with any biological organisms as radiation normally does. And for a while it works, the humans and bio-organisms from Earth2 suffer as Earth prime lobs nuke after nuke across the gate. But eventually the people and organisms of Earth2 are able to resist the effects of high intensity radiation and contamination.

With this new resistance, they start deploying what are essentially giant suicide bugs that detonate into large explosions and spew radiation (an explosion the size of a decent sized bomb but radioactive). The nasty types you'd get from a dirty bomb. Earth prime and its normal non bio enhanced humans can't keep up with this. Deploying the remainder of nuclear warheads, Earth prime is able to secure a small beachhead on the side of Earth2's gate. A nuclear line in the sand is established, and for a moment the giant suicide bug attacks stop.

The only problem, the high amount of radiation is fatal, and even with some of the best NBC surviving is not possible for only a few moments. Electronics aren't having an easy time as the constant radiation screws with sensors, imaging equipment, radar and electronics. The beachhead and surrounding areas are filled to the brim with contaminated radiation, and that level is only increasing with the constant suicide attacks by the dirty giant bomb bugs as time eventually passes.

What device, chemical reaction, plant etc would allow Earth prime to suck up the radiation or nullify the radiation in an area enough such that they could start a full-blown military campaign on the other side. Synthesizing resistance by figuring out how Earth2 and its organisms can survive the radiation isn't a possibility. This device should be capable of protecting an area from harmful radiation/radioactive contaminants but does and should not protect against things like explosions or gunfire. It's not a force field. Secondly it should be semi transportable in that you can somewhat move it. Even after moving it, radiation shouldn't be re-introduced into the area unless the contaminants naturally make their way back in. Think of it as scrubbing or cleaning the environment.

Tech wise say Earth has made some progress to colonizing the moon by this point (w/ only scientists and a small population of civilians) and manned Mars missions are well underway. Remote/autonomous controlled mining of the asteroid belt is just starting and is in its infancy but returning yields.

Limitations wise, you can't use Earth2's organisms/fauna to create an antidote or somehow make humans magically immune to radiation (use of minerals, or particles from Earth2 is fine), the point is to clear a localized area. Magic is out of the question; the solution has to be somewhat related to science.

Science wise, it doesn't need to be rooted in hard science at all. It just has to sound somewhat believable and grounded in some basic logic/reality such that it makes enough sense to not be outright dismissed.

Comment: you can't scrub radiation unless you remove the contaminated material itself, you have to remove all the contaminated soil, there is nothing mobile that will clean radiation without large scale excavation and transport of soil. absorbing radiation does not stop the material from being radioactive.

Comment: What you can do is separate the contaminated material so that exposure to it is trivial. This is how we experience it in nature. It only becomes dangerous when concentrated. But doing this effectively is often beyond our current science.

Answer (score 4):

> Electronics aren't having an easy time as the constant radiation screws with sensors, imaging equipment, radar and electronics

Electronics are not, of course, the only game in town. We already have in real life alternative control systems... they're not generally as good as electronics by all sorts of metrics, but they do exist.

[Fluidics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluidics) is one such technology, which effectively uses very small-scale plumbing in order to perform computation. Its cycle rate is vastly lower than electronics, but it is exceptionally radiation resistant (unless there's enough radiation to boil the liquid, but that would defeat your Earth2 folk as well) and also pretty tolerant to mechanical shocks and vibration. It was posited waaay back in the dark days of 1978 as a way to control nuclear rockets... if you look on page 376 of the PDF of the proceedings of the [Fourth NASA Inter-Center Control Systems Conference](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19780015067/downloads/19780015067.pdf) (its labelled as page 365 on the original document) you'll see "*Application of fluidics to new control components*" for example, showing how fluidic computers can controls pistons and motors and so on.

[Photonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photonics) are another, using purely optical or opto-electronic systems for logic, which have the advantage over fluidics that signals propagate at the speed of light.

This means *basic* control systems for literally any kind of vehicle can made made to operate under conditions that would toast normal electronics. The business of doing serious compute can be pushed back to the less radioactive side of the gate, sending commands over laser links or fibre-optic connections. You can now build "nukedozers" to shovel highly contaminated debris out of the way of the gate to form an initial cordon behind which more complex but less robust equipment can be teleoperated.

> What device, chemical reaction, plant etc would allow Earth prime to suck up the radiation or nullify the radiation in an area enough such that they could start a full-blown military campaign on the other side.

Lets leave aside the pointless stupidity of this action for now, and concentrate on the problem that nothing short of nuclear reactions can "nullify" radiation. Chemical and biological approaches might sequester the radioactives in a convenient form for disposal elsewhere, but the radiation remains. If you want to "nullify" it, you need to break down the unstable isotopes until you end up with stable ones.

Nuclear transmutation is hard, especially because the places in which you can do it (the core of a nuclear reactor) are *also* highly radioactive (and cause problems like [neutron activation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_activation) that you don't really have to worry about outside of active nuclear reactors). If you can build compact neutron sources in the form of miniature fusion reactors you could run a debris reprocessing plant to use fast neutrons generated by D-D and D-T fusion reactions to break up long-lived heavy radio-isotopes, and to fuse the resulting "ash" (radioactive slag, hopefully made up of short-lived isotopes) into glassy bricks for easier disposal, or fashioning into large, warm, radioactive fortifications.

Realistically, the gate will remain an inhospitable nuclear wasteland for years, at a minimum, even with your best efforts to denature the radioactives. Given time, radiation-resistant local plant-life will regrow, but it'll probably be radioactive so it'll have to be chopped down and fed into the vitrifiers. The huge walls of radioactive glass could probably be buried once the fighting has died down.

Honestly, the whole enterprise seems pretty futile.

> This device should be capable of protecting an area from harmful radiation/radioactive contaminants

A sealed, shielded habitat is the best sort of "device" you can hope for. The air will be thick with radioactive dust whenever the weather is dry, because no plants can hope to survive the fight between the bugs and the nuke-dozers. You can't breathe the air, and the water will probably have to be distilled in order to get all the contaminants out. There will be nothing to eat that you didn't bring with you. You can't magically stop highly penetrating gamma or neutron radiation without the aid of thick shielding.

At least you can have windows, so it'll be a bit more cheerful than a submarine, but not be much.

> Synthesizing resistance by figuring out how Earth2 and its organisms can survive the radiation isn't a possibility

Because its magic? Without it there's no scope for long-term survival whilst the Earth2 populace are content to use <s>scorched</s>glowing-earth tactics.

Answer (score 2):

**Augean Stables maneuver.**

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/augean-stables

> the stables in which King Augeas kept 3,000 oxen, and which had not
> been cleaned for 30 years. The cleaning of these stables was
> accomplished by Hercules, who diverted the river Alpheus through them.

Dirty bombs accomplish their dirtying via radioactive particles and dust, which contaminate the area.  The dust came and it can go.  Dilution is the solution to pollution.   You will divert a river and wash the landscape in question.  Once it is washed you can undivert the river and then use the unradioactive landscape for your scheming and plotting.  But leave the sluicegate handy because probably nuke bugs will show up eventually and you will need to clean it again.

Answer (score 0):

> This device should be capable of protecting an area from harmful radiation/radioactive contaminants but does and should not protect against things like explosions or gunfire

Lead wall.

> Secondly it should be semi transportable in that you can somewhat move it

Lead wall on wheels.

Today we protect ourselves from sources of radiation by either removing the source or putting radiation shielding between us and the source. Just ask your dentist. Been working for years. Will likely keep working.

As for bullets and explosions, lead is heavy and soft. It's not ideal armor. It provides soft cover and isn't flammable but we don't make bullet proof vests out of it for a reason.

> But beta particles...

Aluminum foil.

Comment: lead is a horrible idea for mixed radiation, charged particles will actually make the lead radioactive.

Comment: @John [oh really?](https://med-pro.net/what-materials-block-radiation/)

Comment: yes really, read the section in YOUR OWN LINK about neutron radiation and  beta particle radiation. or just read the wiki page for lead shielding  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_shielding

Comment: @John neutron radiation isn't charged. That's why it has that name.

Comment: it also is not the only form of radiation I listed, nor does lead block neutrons, I was originally referring to high energy beta particles, which lead actually makes WORSE.

Comment: FWIW, charged particles don't make lead radioactive but they _do_ result in emission of bremmstrahlung radiation. You can counteract this by making the shield extra thick, but that makes it exceedingly heavy. Neutron radiation won't cause this effect. Lead isn't great for blocking neutron radiation, but it isn't something you'd expect to find in radioactive fallout and waste anyway. You get it from active fission and fusion reactions, which don't happen very much outside of reactors and bomb explosions.

Comment: Wikipedia reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung#Radiation_safety